# how to insert data into data base in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

i am inserting data into data base using following code but data is not inserted in the database 
i am using following code

I am inserting data into iphone application but it does not insert

i have table survey_question_master(question_id,question_text,question_type)

```
- (void) addCoffee {
    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into survey_question_master(question_text,question_type) Values( ? ,?)";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [question_text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [question_type UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        question_ID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}



   - (void) addCoffee:(DataController *)coffeeObj {

    //Add it to the database.
    [coffeeObj addCoffee];
   //Add it to the coffee array.
    [coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];
     NSLog(@"Succeessfully Added");
    }
```

Comment: how are u reading the database that whether it inserts data or not?

Comment: i am opening the data base from sqlite manager to see the inserted data

Comment: Are you getting an error message then? Or does it execute but there's nothing in your database?

Comment: it executes it also shows NSLog successfully added but there is nothing in data base

Comment: However your `NSLog` doesn't test any condition, so all that means is that it didn't crash.  You need to make your `addCoffee` method return `BOOL` and stop using `NSAssert` to report errors.  Also you are calling `addCoffee` twice, which looks dodgy.

Comment: first add coffee inserts item into data base then add object converts all the array items into one object

Comment: might want to consider using a wrapper class of sqlite [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSString *) getDBPath 
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
}

-(void)SaveData:(NSMutableArray *)insertDataArray
{

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    const char *dbPath = [[self getDBPath] UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into items (c1,c2,c3,c4 , c5 ,c6,c7,c8,c9) values (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",[insertDataArray objectAtIndex:0],[insertDataArray objectAtIndex:1],[insertDataArray objectAtIndex:2],[insertDataArray objectAtIndex:3],[insertDataArray objectAtIndex:4],[insertDataArray objectAtIndex:5],[insertDataArray objectAtIndex:6],[insertDataArray objectAtIndex:7],[insertDataArray objectAtIndex:8]];

        NSLog(@"%@",insertSQL);
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &stmt, NULL);

        if(sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"insert success");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"insert un success");
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        int success=sqlite3_step(stmt);

        if (success == SQLITE_ERROR) 
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to insert into the database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(database);

    }

}
```