# If i call this method,then i'm getting a error which is "database is lock".How i can solve this?? Please help me

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

If I call `-(void)insertDataIntoAssemblyAssessment` method,where `finalAssembIdArr` is an array in which must be more than one value, then i'm getting a error which is "**database is lock**".  But, if in `finalAssembIdArr` have just one value,then,value are stored in database successfully.

How I can solve this?? Please help me.

```
-(void)insertDataIntoAssemblyAssessment
{
    sqlite3_stmt *fstatement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    for(int cnt=0; cnt < [finalAssembIdArr count]; cnt++)
    {
        finalAsmbId2=[finalAssembIdArr objectAtIndex:cnt];

        NSLog(@"finalAsmbId2...%@",finalAsmbId2);
        NSLog(@"finalAssessmentIdSt2...%@",finalAssessmentIdSt2);
        NSLog(@"finalFacIdSt2...%@",finalFacIdSt2);
        NSLog(@"finalSpaceIdSt2...%@",finalSpaceIdSt2);

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &ipadSites) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"db opened for AssemblyAssessment..");

            NSString *insertfSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO AssemblyAssessment (assessmentid,spaceid,assemblyid,FacilityID) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",self.finalAssessmentIdSt2,self.finalSpaceIdSt2,self.finalAsmbId2,self.finalFacIdSt2];

            NSLog(@"insertfSQL...%@",insertfSQL);


            const char *insert_fstmt = [insertfSQL UTF8String];
                sqlite3_prepare_v2(ipadSites,insert_fstmt,-1,&fstatement,NULL);
                NSLog(@"inserting AssemblyAssessment..");

            if (sqlite3_step(fstatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                NSLog(@"Add value in AssemblyAssessment...");

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Insert failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(ipadSites));
                NSLog(@"Failed to add value in AssemblyAssessment...");
            } 
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(fstatement);
        sqlite3_close(ipadSites);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please... ! Don't open/close SQLite connection in loop like that! 
Open handle to database outside from the "FOR loop". 
Please look here [how to insert data into data base in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717400/how-to-insert-data-into-data-base-in-iphone) and here [How to insert NSMutableArray elements in Sqlite3 in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087014/how-to-insert-nsmutablearray-elements-in-sqlite3-in-iphone?rq=1)

And, for the basic CRUD (create, read, update, delete), I suggest you .. to take a look at [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the database in SQLite or any other browser ?? If database is opened from outside, it gives same error. Check it. I had same issue.